# Domain forwarding keep links

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, forwarding

I have domains whit one registrar and the hosting whit an other company.

Now i want to forward all domains to the main Domain but keep the Link structure.

For example: maindomain.com/something/ is the path of my website-

Now i want to forward all domains to this website like domain.net, domain.de, domain.eu etc.

- But important is that

  maindomain.com/something/permalink is the same as domain.xx/permalink
  and also shows in the addressbar.

  So all domains pointing at the same location but will still keep
  there ".xx" and will show the "/permalink"

I could´t find anything on that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't actually concern much with PHP and Wordpress. You'll want to search your domain registrar for how to create a domain pointer.

On the server that actually handles the requests and has the Wordpress install, you'll need to make sure it accepts the domainpointer by adding a record of it in your management tool, typically DirectAdmin.

Comment: Hey HappyBacon,

Thank for answering exactly that is the twist i have no idea how to o that. 

For now i was usually using normal forwarding methods, but now this is a different task and I could use a little help.

Comment: The procedure to follow really depends on your registrar. You have to log into their back-end and point the domain to your main one.

Then on your main one log into DirectAdmin (or you server's equivalent of that) and create a domainpointer. That last one can easily be googled.

Comment: thanks mate! This is a good point! 

Sounds like the thing i´m after, since its the first time i´m doing this.

the domain i want to forward need to be the Alias of the domain i want to forward to right?

Now if i do this will the link structure be the same?  like i end up at the same page if i go for example.com/something and exampleAlias.me/something 

And now the most difficult thing witch gives me a headache is that the main website is within a folder  like example.com/folder/website

Now of cause want the alias domains to skip /folder and only display /website

thanks a lot!